# Classification with Weka+ NaiveBayes Classifier+ Text classification

Tags: weka, document-classification

I'm using Weka for text classification task.
I created my data.arff File. It contains two attributes:

1. text attribute
2. class attribute

Then, the generated ARFF file is processed with the StringToWordVector:

> java weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.StringToWordVector -i data/weather.arff -o data/out.arff
>   Then, NaiveBayes is used:
>   java weka.classifiers.bayes.NaiveBayes -t data/out.arff -K

I have this problem:

> weka.core.UnsupportedAttributeTypeException: weka.classifiers.bayes.NaiveBayes: Cannot handle numeric class!
>       at weka.core.Capabilities.test(Capabilities.java:954)
>       at weka.core.Capabilities.test(Capabilities.java:1110)
>       at weka.core.Capabilities.test(Capabilities.java:1023)
>       at weka.core.Capabilities.testWithFail(Capabilities.java:1302)
>       at weka.classifiers.bayes.NaiveBayes.buildClassifier(NaiveBayes.java:213)
>       at weka.classifiers.Evaluation.evaluateModel(Evaluation.java:1076)
>       at weka.classifiers.Classifier.runClassifier(Classifier.java:312)
>       at weka.classifiers.bayes.NaiveBayes.main(NaiveBayes.java:944)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at weka.gui.SimpleCLIPanel$ClassRunner.run(SimpleCLIPanel.java:265)

Could anyone help me?
I'm stuck at this level.

Answer (score 0):

It's exactly what it says - it cannot handle numeric values for the class variable. If you declared the class variable to be string, change the numeric values to their equivalent text values.